# Excel File Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, amazon-s3

I try to save an excel file to S3 but i have some problems ,

```
$file = Excel::create('' . $date . '' , function($excel) use ($licencies) {
        $excel->sheet('Excel', function($sheet) use ($licencies)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($licencies);

        });

    });
```

i would like to store the file to s3

```
    $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');

    $s3->put($file->store("xlsx", false, true)['full'] , 'upload');
```

I file get uploaded but when i try to open the file i get an error.

When i save the file to app/storage i can read the file perfectly !

Hope someone could help me ... it's begin to be a nightmare

Comment: Can you post the error you get when you try to read the file?, I have an idea of what may be happening but I need to make sure.